# Issue when performing firestore actions after creating user account

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

After creating a user in `firebase`, it seems that the `firestore` actions are not happening, it creates the user in the authentication but the firestore database does not create the data (I don't get any error logs):

```
const idFarmacia = null
  try {
    const { user } = await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email,
      password,
    )

    const createFarmacia: CreateFarmaciaProps = {
      nome: nomeDaFarmacia,
      tipo: tipoDeFarmacia,
      dataCriacao: customMoment('toBrasilISO'),
      gerentes: [
        {
          id: user.uid,
          tipoDeUsuario,
        },
      ],
    }

    if (getValues('tipoDeFarmacia') === FarmaciaEnum[0]) {
      createFarmacia.cnpj = cnpj
    } else {
      createFarmacia.rg = rg
    }

    await firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .set({
        email: email.toLowerCase(),
        telefone,
        cidade: cidade || '',
        dataCriacao: customMoment('toBrasilISO'),
        validado: false,
        tipoDeUsuario,
        idFarmacia: '',
      })

    const { id } = await firestore()
      .collection('farmacias')
      .add(createFarmacia)

    await firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).update({
      idFarmacia: id,
    })

    Toast.show({
      type: 'success',
      text1: 'Conta criada com sucesso!',
    })
  } catch (err: any) {
    if (idFarmacia) {
      await firestore().collection('farmacias').doc(idFarmacia).delete()
    }
    const message = verifyErroCode(err.code)
    Toast.show({
      type: 'error',
      text1: message,
    })
  }
}
```